# What is $\sin^{-1}(]\sin(x)-\varepsilon,\sin(x)+\varepsilon[)$?

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry

The subject is : prove that $\sin:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous using this definition:
$$
\forall W\in \mathcal{V_{\sin(x)}}, \sin^{-1}(W)\in \mathcal{V}_x
$$

let $\varepsilon>0, W=]\sin(x)-\varepsilon,\sin(x)+\varepsilon[$

So I have to find $ \sin^{-1}(]\sin(x)-\varepsilon,\sin(x)+\varepsilon[)$ and see if it is a neighborhood of $x$ in $(\mathbb{R},|.|)$

$$
\sin^{-1}(]\sin(x)-\varepsilon,\sin(x)+\varepsilon[)=
\{y\in \mathbb{R}, \sin(y)\in ]\sin(x)-\varepsilon,\sin(x)+\varepsilon[\}$$

can I say that $\sin^{-1}(\sin(x)-\varepsilon)<y<\sin^{-1}(\sin(x)+\varepsilon)$ ?

But how to continue?

Thank you

Comment: You can do that only on a monotone interval. Without knowing the "goal" of this exercise is, it is hard to tell, what you are then supposed to do specifically. Maybe you are already done. More information is needed.

Comment: @Imago i want to prove that $\sin:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous using the definition of image inverse

Comment: @ Poline Sandra you should definitely add that information in your problem text and the exact definition of continuity you are using.

Comment: @Imago I added all the informations

Answer (score 1):

Because $|\sin(x)-\sin(y)| \leq |x-y|$, $\sin^{-1}((\sin(x)-\varepsilon,\sin(x)+\varepsilon))$ contains $(x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon)$, and thus is a neighborhood of $x$ according to the definition of "neighborhood" I have in mind. Does this match the definition you have in mind? If not then I will edit.

Comment: but what is equal to :$ \sin^{-1}((\sin(x)-\varepsilon,\sin(x)+\varepsilon))$

Comment: @PolineSandra That's not a tractable problem to solve exactly. Solving it is not necessary to prove continuity of $\sin$.

Comment: but in the exercise we have to find: $\sin^{-1}((\sin(x)-\varepsilon,\sin(x)+\varepsilon))$

Comment: @PolineSandra Are you specifically asked to write down an explicit formula for the preimage? Because you can't do it in general.

Comment: why we can't do it in general ?

Comment: @PolineSandra Because it essentially requires exact evaluation of the arcsine, which can only really be done in terms of an infinite sum or similar. You're reading the description in the wrong way: the point is that for any given neighborhood $W$ of $\sin(x)$ you furnish *some* neighborhood $N$ of $x$ such that $\sin(y) \in W$ for all $y \in N$. The neighborhood $N$ doesn't have to be optimal.

Comment: I don't understand

Comment: @PolineSandra When you ask for $\sin^{-1}(W)$ you're asking for the largest possible neighborhood $N$ of $x$ such that $\sin(y) \in W$ for all $y \in N$. You don't need to get the largest possible one. To prove continuity, it's sufficient to just produce some neighborhood.

Comment: in my mind I want to do something like this: we know that $|\sin(x)\leq 1$ then $\sin(x)-\varepsilon<1$ and after that I consider two cases for any epsilon such that $\sin(x)+\varepsilon\leq 1$ and $\sin(x)+\varepsilon>1$ the same thing for $\sin(x)-\varepsilon$

Comment: @PolineSandra That part (dealing with the question of whether your interval in the codomain contains an extremum or not) isn't the problem, it's the part where you try to exactly obtain $\sin^{-1}(\sin(x) \pm \varepsilon)$. In any case, it is easier to avoid case work altogether by following the suggestion in my answer.

Comment: ok so about your answer how  you use that $|\sin(x)-\sin(y)|\leq |x-y|$

Comment: That means that $\sin^{-1}((\sin(x)-\varepsilon,\sin(x)+\varepsilon))$ contains $(x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon)$ and is thus a neighborhood of $x$.